# T-SQL Unequal Decile based on totals in another column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I didn't see an exact answer for what I was looking for. I have a table with an ID and two values.  I need to sort the first value column low to high and then decile the list based on each decile having an equal (or almost equal) total value 2. Here's an example using quartiles for space considerations:

I have:

```
ID  value1  value2      
1     2      132        
2     6      182        
3     5      195        
4     8      152        
5     3      132        
6     9      129        
7     3      180        
8     9      120        
9     3      172        
10    6      192        
11    9      177        
12    12     151
```

Each quartile should about about                478.5

Sorting by value1 gets this but I need to be able to assign my quartile where each is about 478.5.  I have manually entered sample quartiles which may or may not be correct based on the calculations

```
ID  value1  value2  Qtle    
1     2      132      1 
5     3      132      1 
7     3      180      1 
9     3      172      2 
3     5      195      2 
2     6      182      3 
10    6      192      3 
4     8      152      3 
6     9      129      4 
8     9      120      4 
11    9      177      4 
12   12      151      4
```

Sorry about the formatting - first post.

Edit 1 - I think I might have solved it, although it's probably not as elegant as it could be

Edit 2 - Added sample quartiles above and fixed the code below to reflect quartiles instead of deciles. Also fixed the sum of value2

```
SELECT value1
    ,value2
,SUM(value2) OVER (ORDER BY value1 ) CumSum
,CASE
    WHEN SUM(value2) OVER (ORDER BY value1 ) < (Select sum(value2) from table1)/4 Then 1 
   WHEN SUM(value2) OVER (ORDER BY value1 ) < 2 * (Select sum(value2) from 
table1)/4 Then 2 
    WHEN SUM(value2) OVER (ORDER BY value1 ) < 3 * (Select sum(value2) from 
table1)/4 Then 3 
    Else 4 
 End as Quartile
FROM Table1
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: T-SQL ...it's enough

Comment: @Black.Jack Yes, but it should be in the tags.

Comment: Where did you get the value 396.5 from? Can you specify an expected output?

Comment: Sorry, the 396.5 is the total of value2 divided by 4.

Comment: To answer GolfWolf's second question,  Each record is assigned a quartile but since the sum of any combination of records isn't exactly 396.5, it's difficult to split up the dataset in 4 equal parts.  Each quartile will never equal 396.5.

Comment: @elsolo21 Sorry, this is still totally unclear... Your SQL code does not compile and your statement *Sorry, the 396.5 is the total of value2 divided by 4* is wrong, as `SELECT SUM(value2)/(4.0) FROM @Table1;` returns `478,5` with your sample data. Please state your expected output, fitting to the given sample data, and try to explain the rules you want to apply. I have no idea at the moment...

Comment: @Shnugo You're absolutely correct, the total was wrong. I fixed that above, added some sample quartiles and modified my SQL to reflect only quartiles.  I tried my SQL on my real dataset and it seemed to give me what I was looking for.

Comment: Hi, one question left: Is it on purpose, that the running summa is the same for all with the same `value1`? If you'd inlcude the `value2` to the `ORDER BY` within `OVER` you'd get dedicated values for each row (as long as v1 and v2 are unique - in combination). Just check it out. I included this value to the resultset to check this easily...

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've got this correctly...

The following is a generic approach. You can specify the `@TileCount` with a variable:

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE(ID INT,value1 INT,value2 INT);
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES      
 (1,2,132)        
,(2,6,182)        
,(3,5,195)        
,(4,8,152)        
,(5,3,132)        
,(6,9,129)        
,(7,3,180)        
,(8,9,120)        
,(9,3,172)        
,(10,6,192)        
,(11,9,177)        
,(12,12,151);

DECLARE @TileCount INT=4;

WITH Sums AS
(
    SELECT TOP (@TileCount) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS TileRank
              ,A.SumTotal
              ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) * (A.SumTotal / CAST(@TileCount AS FLOAT)) AS SumPart  
    FROM master..spt_values
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT (SELECT SUM(value2) FROM @Table1) AS SumTotal)AS A
)
,AddCumSum AS
(
    SELECT value1
          ,value2
          ,SUM(value2) OVER (ORDER BY value1) CumSum
     FROM @Table1
)
SELECT AddCumSum.*
      ,A.SumPart
      ,A.TileRank AS Tile
FROM AddCumSum
OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Sums WHERE CumSum<=SumPart ORDER BY TileRank ASC) AS A;
```

The result

```
+--------+--------+--------+---------+------+
| value1 | value2 | CumSum | SumPart | Tile |
+--------+--------+--------+---------+------+
| 2      | 132    | 132    | 478,5   | 1    |
+--------+--------+--------+---------+------+
| 3      | 132    | 616    | 957     | 2    |
+--------+--------+--------+---------+------+
| 3      | 180    | 616    | 957     | 2    |
+--------+--------+--------+---------+------+
| 3      | 172    | 616    | 957     | 2    |
+--------+--------+--------+---------+------+
| 5      | 195    | 811    | 957     | 2    |
+--------+--------+--------+---------+------+
| 6      | 182    | 1185   | 1435,5  | 3    |
+--------+--------+--------+---------+------+
| 6      | 192    | 1185   | 1435,5  | 3    |
+--------+--------+--------+---------+------+
| 8      | 152    | 1337   | 1435,5  | 3    |
+--------+--------+--------+---------+------+
| 9      | 120    | 1763   | 1914    | 4    |
+--------+--------+--------+---------+------+
| 9      | 129    | 1763   | 1914    | 4    |
+--------+--------+--------+---------+------+
| 9      | 177    | 1763   | 1914    | 4    |
+--------+--------+--------+---------+------+
| 12     | 151    | 1914   | 1914    | 4    |
+--------+--------+--------+---------+------+
```

### Some explanation

The CTE `Sums` computes some values which allows to use them as *named variables*. The `@TileCount` is used within the `TOP` clause in connection with `ROW_NUMBER()` selecting from `master..spt_values`. This is nothing else than a well filled table. We are not interested in the values, we just need it as the base to get a running number.

The second CTE `AddCumSum` returns the result with the running summa.

The final `SELECT` finds the smallest TileRank fitting to the running summa.